# Random point on VideoDisplay isn't accurate enough

Tags: apache-flex, flv, keyframe, videodisplay

For a schoolassigment me and some buddies of mine are creating an application that is showing many similarities with the C-Mon & Kypski musicvideo on www.oneframeoffame.com. The application is being developed in Flex.

We want to get a random point of a clip, let it pause so a user can mimic the pose and make a snapshot out of it.

What i managed to do is get a random point of the movie. I did this by getting a random value between 0 and de total duration of the movie.

But what i didn't managed to do is let the screen pause on every 24st of a frame. As the movie concist out of 24FPS. It looks like the the random value of the movie that is being requested is being rounded by the movie itself. As example: There appears to be no difference between the frames requested at 2.40 or 2.41.

It appears it got something to do with keyframing i've read on the Adobe® Flex™ 3.5 Language Reference. The movie is a FLV file and i use the VideoDisplay object to display the movie.

Does someone is familiar with this or knows a solution to my problem?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the VideoDisplay object myself, but from what you've mentioned, there may be two solutions.

1. Add more keyframes when you encode your video. This will make it larger, but will allow you to seek more accurately.
2. Seek to the previous keyframe, and allow the video to play until it reaches your desired location.